# How To Decode Contract When only Know Address Contract, No ABI?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment

I know the contract address. Unknown ABI . So how do I Decode that contract.. I use bytecode-decompiler in EtherScan but It only decodes Function unknow.
[image]

So how to Decode the full code Contract .

example contract:  https://etherscan.io/address/0x74de5d4fcbf63e00296fd95d33236b9794016631#code

Answer (score 0):

Getting back to the exact source code of an unverified smart contract is, unfortunately, not possible.

Your best bet is to use a bytecode decompiler like the one you used (Etherscan's solution). As an alternative I can also recommend EtherVM:

https://ethervm.io/decompile